# Slicing in mongoengine

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine, nosql

I have a Thread document which has within it Comments, which are EmbeddedDocuments. I don't want to have all of the comments return at once, but instead display them ten at a time.

In PyMongo or with just MongoDB I know I could use the $slice operator, but I'm not sure of how to do this with mongoengine. If I do

```
Thread.objects.get(id=thread_id).comments[:10]
```

will it only fetch those ten from the database?

Cheers!

Comment: I don't know the full answer but the slice is done *after* the fetch so it will get all of the comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Support has been added in the dev branch and will make the next release!

You can return only 10 comments by using the fields and slice method:

```
thread = Thread.objects.fields(slice__comments=10).get(id=thread_id)
```